# AudioUnit project templates for Xcode 4?

Tags: macos, sdk, core-audio, audiounit

I just tried to start writing an AudioUnit effect plug-in for Lion (*not* iOS) but noticed that the AudioUnit templates are not present in Xcode 4 any more. I've tried finding them on the Apple Dev centre sites but had no luck, even the link in the Audio Unit Programming Guide is dead! Has anyone got any idea where I can get some templates or why they are missing? I really don't want to have to write all that boilerplate code myself...

Comment: Are you sure your Xcode install is complete? The templates are still there in Xcode 4.1 under Mac OS X -> System Plug-ins -> Audio Unit Effect. They have even new icons (compared to Xcode3).

Answer (score 0):

On XCode 4.2.1 under Mac OS X -> System Plug-ins the list I see is:

Generic C++ Plug-in, 
Generic Kernel Extension, 
Image Unit Plug-in, 
IOKit Driver, 
Preference Pane, 
Quick Look Plug-In, 
Screen Saver, 
Spotlight Importer, 
Sync Schema

No Audio Unit project templates.